# Is the quantum relative entropy a Bregman divergence?

Tags: convex-analysis, information-theory, quantum-mechanics, information-geometry

This is related to [a broader question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812047/what-is-the-essential-difference-between-classical-and-quantum-information-geome) about quantum information geometry - this question is more specific.

A fundamental concept in [Amari's treatment of information geometry](https://www.springer.com/jp/book/9784431559771) is that of a Bregman divergence. Given a convex function $\psi(\mathbf{x})$, a Bregman divergence is defined as
$$
D_\psi(\mathbf{x}\|\mathbf{x}_0) = \psi(\mathbf{x}) - \psi(\mathbf{x}_0) - \nabla \psi(\mathbf{x}_0)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0).
$$
Bregman divergences are non-negative and are zero when $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_0$, and they behave in some ways like the square of a distance between $\mathbf{x}_0$ and $\mathbf{x}$. (Though taking the square root does not form a metric.)

An example is the Kullback-Leibler divergence between two probability distributions, $D_{KL}(P\|P^0)=\sum_{i=1}^N p_i\log\frac{p_i}{p^0_i}$. In the case of finite support can be seen (for example) by parameterising each distribution by its first $N-1$ probabilities (so $p_N=1-\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}p_i$) and then taking $\psi$ to be the negative entropy, $\psi=\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_i\log p_i$.

In quantum theory, the natural analog of the Kullback-Leibler divergence is the quantum relative entropy, $$
D_Q(\rho\|\rho_0) = \mathrm{Tr}\,\rho(\log\rho - \log\rho_0),
$$
where $\rho$ and $\rho_0$ are density matrices and $\log$ is the matrix logarithm.

My question is, in the case of a finite Hilbert space (or indeed in general), can the quantum relative entropy be expressed as a Bregman divergence? If so, what is the right way to parameterise $\rho$ so that this becomes clear?

Comment: $\rho = \psi \circ \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue map and your underlying Hilbert space is the real-symmetric matrices with the trace inner product.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 3):

I think the following paper answers your question: https://users.renyi.hu/~petz/pdf/112bregman.pdf

> Abstract: In this paper the Bregman operator divergence is introduced
>   for density matrices by differentiation of the matrix-valued function
>   $x \mapsto x log x$. This quantity is compared with the relative
>   operator entropy of Fujii and Kamei. It turns out that the trace is
>   the usual Umegaki's relative entropy which is the only intersection of
>   the classes of quasi-entropies and Bregman divergences.

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed look like an answer - it shows that the quantum relative entropy is a Bregman divergence with $\psi=\operatorname{Tr}\rho\log\rho$ (in my notation). I'll accept this after reading it more thoroughly.